# beyondcode laravel-websocket not connecting on server

Tags: laravel, websocket, server, laravel-websockets

I am trying to build a chat app and for that using [beyondcode/laravel-websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets). When I used it in local it was working great but on the server can not make it run.

## My Configurations are as follows

### My Echo Settings (Js/Bootstrap.js)

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: false,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
});
```

### My Pusher Settings (Broadcasting.php)

```
'pusher' => [
     'driver' => 'pusher',
     'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
     'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
     'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
  'options' => [
     'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
     'encrypted' => false,
     'host' => env('WEBSOCKET_HOST'),
     'port' => env('WEBSOCKET_PORT'),
     'scheme' => env('WEBSSOCKET_SCHEME'),
 ],
],
```

### My Webscoket Settings (Websockets.php)

```
'dashboard' => [
       'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
],

 'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => true,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],
```

### My .env Configuration

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=MyDefaultIdForURMENU
PUSHER_APP_KEY=1234567
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=MyDefaultSecretForURMENU
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

WEBSOCKET_HOST = 127.0.0.1

WEBSOCKET_PORT = 6001

WEBSSOCKET_SCHEME= http

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Now when I run websocket either directly in ssh or using setsid using command

```
php artisan websockets:serve
```

#### OR

```
setsid php artisan websockets:serve
```

it shows

> Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...

But the console log is showing either

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com/app/1234567?protocol=7&client=js&version=5.0.3&flash=false' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

#### OR Sometimes

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://mydomain.com:6001/app/1234567?protocol=7&client=js&version=5.0.3&flash=false' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

Please guide me what's I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

Hi there guys I was having this problem and I searched the internet top to bottom and finally did the following to make it work on VPS

**1- Config/broadcasting.php**

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'useTLS' => true,
        'encrypted' => true,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'https',
        'curl_options' => [
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        ]
    ]
]
```

**2- Resources/js/bootstrap.js**

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    forceTLS: true,
    encrypted: true,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    enabledTransports: ['ws','wss'],
    disableStats: true
});
```

**3- Config/websockets.php**

```
'ssl' => [
    /*
     * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
     * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
     * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
     * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
     */
    'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),

    /*
     * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
     * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
     */
    'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),

    /*
     * Passphrase for your local_cert file.
     */
    'passphrase' => null,
    'verify_peer' => false
],
```

**4- .env**

```
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT="../ssl/certs/filename.crt"
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK="../ssl/keys/filename.key"
```

Step 3 and 4 are also important like 1 and 2 you need to provide .crt and .key files paths. The path can different for different servers you can move up to public_html folder in your cpanel file manager and find ssl folder for these files.